# I want to edit documents on my blog without the need to download and upload files again

Tags: attachments

Would that be possible?

Basically, I need something which will enable me to edit files directly at the server...

any help would be much appreciated....

Comment: does the ***appearance -> editor*** not work for you?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I want to edit my attachments (photos, documents, spreadsheets, etc) without the need for download/upload

Comment: You have to be more clear on what type of documents and exactly what you want to edit.

Comment: photos, documents, spreadsheets, etc

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on your question and the comment on Viruthagiri's answer, you want to edit your documents and attachments using WordPress.  I'm afraid WordPress doesn't offer a feature to edit documents and images using their backend.  The only thing I can say is to either use an FTP client (WinSCP [free] is a good one for PC, and Cyberduck [free] or Transmit [$39] for Mac OS X) to upload and replace the files in the WordPress upload directory.

Comment: No. I don't want to edit files with wordpress. I want something which would allow me to click at the attachment link, native application opens and I can edit the file normally....now, when I save document in dative application, I want new (updated) version to be uploaded to my blog automatically.

Comment: I'm going to say again, that's what FTP is for.  You can't open a file in a native editor without downloading the CURRENT file from the server and then re-uploading the file.  What you want to do is beyond the limit of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ftp?. Just use editors like dreamweaver, phpdesigner and there are many more editors available. You can download 30 day free trial.

List of php editors [available here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors).

I highly recommend [notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to edit my attachments (photos, documents, spreadsheets, etc) without the need for download/upload